# Clear notification on Action Button click

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, notifications, android-pendingintent

I am trying to clear an notification when an user clicken on the action button. I searched a lot on stackoverflow and google, tried a lot but all failed. So I was wondering, if there is any solution how to fix it?

My code for creating notification:

```
final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_info_black_24dp);
builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("Geschiedenis \nFrans \nDuits \nNatuurkunde \nWiskunde"));
builder.setContentTitle("Rooster: ");
builder.setOngoing(true);
builder.setAutoCancel(true);
builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
builder.setAutoCancel(true);
Intent showIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, showIntent, 0);
builder.addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel, "Sluiten",  contentIntent);
builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

So to be clear: I would like to clear (close) the notification once "Sluiten" is clicked.

Comment: You'd better function it by yourself. Create a notification with a certain ID. Add a custom button on your custom layout and set it an action to cancel notification with that certain ID

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To close the notification when the "Sluiten" link is clicked on the notification I have included a working version of code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    NotificationManager notificationManager;
    Button notificationBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if(getIntent()!=null && getIntent().hasExtra(getPackageName())){
            notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID); //closes notification
        }
        notificationBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.notificationBtn);
        notificationBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.notificationBtn:
                showNotification();
                break;
        }
    }

    void showNotification(){
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_account_box_black_24dp);
        builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("Geschiedenis \nFrans \nDuits \nNatuurkunde \nWiskunde"));
        builder.setContentTitle("Rooster: ");
        builder.setOngoing(true);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        Intent showIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        showIntent.putExtra(getPackageName(), NOTIFICATION_ID); // this line sets off closing notification in onCreate()
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, showIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel, "Sluiten",  contentIntent);
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
    }


}
```

**NOTE**
In the previous answer I did not include the line

```
showIntent.putExtra(getPackageName(), NOTIFICATION_ID); // this line sets off closing notification in onCreate()
```

which is essential to closing the notification on click

Comment: I have edited my answer.  I neglected an important line of code you needed.

Comment: Well I do not have an custom view for notification, and so it cant find `findViewById(R.id.notificationBtn)`

Comment: That part doesn't matter.  That's just where I invoked the showNotification() function to test it.  You can call showNotification however you like

Comment: It works indeed!!! Thanks man, you made my day! Is there also an possibilty to close the notification without opening the app? (so for example I launch the notification, leave the app, then click "Sluiten", that it will only close the notification and not open the app)

Comment: Glad to hear!  If your initial question was answered, upvote and select it as the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115559/discussion-between-user3331142-and-jason).